# Copy From One Range, Paste To The Same Row But Columns To The Left

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

My below code is not running? Can't seem to figure out why...

I'm attempting to copy a named range 22 columns to the left of it using the following code, can someone steer me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Sub ApplyFutureYears()

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws0 As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim destRng1 As String
Dim sorceRng1 As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws0 = wb.Sheets("Selection")
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Non-Union Empl HC")

Select Case ws0.Range("G3")

    Case "2015LRP"
        sorceRng1 = "Copy1": destRng1 = Range("Copy1").Offset(0, -22)

    Case Else

        Exit Sub

End Select

ws1.Range(sorceRng1).Copy
ws1.Range(destRng1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are some changes I would suggest:

```
Set ws0 = wb.ActiveSheet
```

and

```
Select Case ws0.Range("G3").name
```

and also instead of using the copy command why not just assign values directly, for example:

```
ws1.range(ws1.cells(1, 20), ws1.cells(10, 2)).value= ws0.range(ws0.cells(1, 1), ws0.cells(10, 1)).value
```